# setting up Xorg input devices without udev

Tags: xorg, udev, input

I have `udev` support in kernel(`CONFIG_DEVTMPFS`), thus my system does not strictly require `udev daemon`. Indeed everything works fine without `udev daemon` with the exception of `Xorg` (`LXDE`).

`LXDE` starts fine, but keyboard and mouse are not working.

[A related question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/503617/xorg-input-devices-fail-without-udev) suggests I need to modify my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to not use udev, but specify input devices manually.

These are the relevant sections in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

How do I need to change my `xorg.conf` so that my input devices work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following section:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier   "Layout[all]"
  InputDevice  "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
  InputDevice  "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
  Option       "AutoAddDevices" "off"
EndSection
```

To find the correct mouse and keyboard drivers, I suggest you inspect `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` before you turn udev off: you will see which driver it selects, and which options it may apply to them.