# Fn keyboard keys not working (when udev is disabled)

Tags: keyboard, udev, keyboard-layout

I am in the process of getting rid of `udev daemon` from my system. I have fixed [all issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274149/setting-up-xorg-input-devices-without-udev), only one small problem is remaining:

It used to be (when I was using udev), that <kbd>Fn+Down</kbd> acted as `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and <kbd>Fn+UP</kbd> acted as `XF86MonBrightnessUp`, so that I could create a keybinding in Openbox for `xbacklight -dec 5` and `xbacklight -inc 5` respectively to change display brightness.

When I boot my laptop without `udev`, these keys no longer work. Other <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys such as <kbd>Fn+Pause</kbd> or <kbd>Fn+SysRq</kbd> work fine.

Looking with `xev`, I see following when I press <kbd>Fn+Down</kbd>,

```
KeyPress event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xb9, subw 0x0, time 952589, (169,-10), root:(1040,435),
    state 0x10, keycode 101 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xb9, subw 0x0, time 952589, (169,-10), root:(1040,435),
    state 0x10, keycode 101 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How can I make my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work again ?

I am using LXDE (Openbox) on Debian.

**UPDATE**

I have discovered a file `/lib/udev/keymaps/dell` which apparently idev uses to set up the keymap. It contains, among other lines:

```
0x85 brightnessdown # Fn+Down arrow Brightness Down
0x86 brightnessup # Fn+Up arrow Brightness Up
```

so how can I map this file manually, without udev?
What command do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I overlook something, but isn't this just a matter of adding the `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` to your xmodmap?

`xmodmap -e "keycode 101 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown"` for testing this temporarily. Similar for brightness up.

If it works, you need to make this permanent depending on your display manager. LXDE has LXDM, so make your changes according to [here](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/Xsession?h=packages/lxdm) (xmodmap handling starts at line 39) after you modify a keymap generated with `xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap` permanently as tested with the xmodmap modification above.

Comment: thanks. Works fine now, both for BrightnessUp and BrightnessDown.

Comment: I am using `SLIM` as my login manager. Do you happen to know how to add the xmodmap changes to slim ?

Comment: If you put a call to xmodmap in your .xinitrc file as so: `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, it should work. It means that  your brightness change works only after login, but this is a feature, not a bug. Sometimes, a `sh -c 'sleep 30 && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap'` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

With `udev` *on*, get your keyboard layout with:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY mylayout.xkb
```

Then you should be able to load it (once `udev` is *off*) by:

```
xkbcomp -i <XInput_id> mylayout.xkb $DISPLAY
```

where `<XInput_id>` can be found by `xinput list` or `grep XINPUT /var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

References that may be of interest: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb) and [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274246/convert-xmodmap-to-custom-xkb-file-and-load-it-from-home-directory-customize) (not an exact duplicate).